# How can we get the starting address of task_struct of a process

Tags: linux, c

Suppose I wrote a C program and then it got executed on system. If I want to know the starting address of the `task_struct` for the corresponding running program, how I can find that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside kernel code, the current process is available as the `current` pointer: include `linux/sched.h`, and then you can access any member of `task_struct` for the current process by writing, for example, `current->pid`.

(`current` itself may be a macro; for example on x86 it’s replaced by `get_current()`.)

See [chapter 2 of *Linux Device Drivers*](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch02.pdf), in particular “The Current Process”.